# How to have both uppercase and lowercase in this Python function?

Tags: python

I tried to do `upper()` and `lower()` and even changing the Y and N's to lowercase inside the code. It works if I put in uppercase `Y` and `N` but I keep getting errors if I type in lowercase `y` or `n`. Anyone know a solution?

```
def patternSum(myDice):
    if allSame(myDice):
       patternPoints=input("\nWould you like to score the pattern points for all different values (25 points)? [Y/N]: ")
       patternPoints.lower()
       if patternPoints == "Y":
          points = 25
          sumDice=input("Would you like to score the sum of the dice (16 points)? [Y/N]: ")
          if sumDice == "Y":
             points = 25 + 16
          if sumDice == "Y":
             points = 16
       elif patternPoints == "N":
          sumDice=input("Would you like to score the sum of the dice (16 points)? [Y/N]: ")
          points = 16
       else:
          print("Please try again by entering Y or N.")
    else:
        points = sum(myDice)
        print( "Your score is now:",patternSum([1,1,1,1,1]),".\n" )

    return points
score = score + patternSum(myDice)
```

Comment: First of all, doing patternPoints.lower() will not convert patternPoitns to lower case string. You actually have to put it into a variable.
Secondly, I don't know what you're doing with "if allSame(myDice):". Are you just trying to put the concept ? Because I'm not sure if that's a correct syntax of writing if block in Python.

Comment: I think you should consider putting `patternPoints.lower()` to a variable first. Because `lower()` and `upper()` does not mutate the original string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you posted, you put lower() and compare to a upper case input, but,
the lower() and upper() functions return the transformed string, it does not alter the current string.

I've changed your code to:

```
def patternSum(myDice):
    if allSame(myDice):
       patternPoints=input("\nWould you like to score the pattern points for all different values (25 points)? [Y/N]: ")
       if patternPoints.lower() == "y":
          points = 25
          sumDice=input("Would you like to score the sum of the dice (16 points)? [Y/N]: ")
          if sumDice.upper() == "Y":
             points = 25 + 16
          if sumDice == "Y":
             points = 16
       elif patternPoints.upper() == "n":
          sumDice=input("Would you like to score the sum of the dice (16 points)? [Y/N]: ")
          points = 16
       else:
          print("Please try again by entering Y or N.")
    else:
        points = sum(myDice)
        print( "Your score is now:",patternSum([1,1,1,1,1]),".\n" )

    return points
score = score + patternSum(myDice)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not updating the value to the variable `patternPoints`.

`patternPoints.lower()` doesn't change the value of `patternPoints`.

You should have done `patternPoints = patternPoints.upper()` on 4th line.